# Can I use event.target to determine an index of <li> element?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, html-lists

Suppose i have a `<ul></ul>` with some number of `<li></li>` elements. And I wonder, what is the best way to get an index of the `<li>` element by clicking on its child (I have buttons inside)? Under the best way, I mean the most beginner-friendly, using vanilla JS. Maybe you, guys, have a couple of ideas to share?

I need that index to remove the related element from an array later on. What I've managed to write so far seems overcomplicated, since I have to assign ids to each element I want to click on.

```
function removeItem(e) {
   if (e.target.classList.contains('removeBtn')) {
      controller.tasks.splice(e.target.id, 1);
      view.renderInput(controller.tasks);
   } 
}
ulEl.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
```

Comment: Use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an array, that can contain an object (ex. li element) as a key.

Comment: And you can use [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the `li` the button is in: `const li = e.target.closest("li"); if (li.contains(e.target)) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: When you render your array as HTML, add `data-index="0"` etc to the delete button. That way you can read the index from `this.dataset.index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose i have a `<ul></ul>` with some number of `<li></li>` elements. And I wonder, what is the best way to get an index of the `<li>` element by clicking on its child (I have buttons inside)?

Just use `forEach` which will give you the index as well like this:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('#someList li');
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('#someList button');

btns.forEach((btn, index) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(list[index]);
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="someList">
  <li>A <button>Click Me</button></li>
  <li>B <button>Click Me</button></li>
  <li>C <button>Click Me</button></li>
  <li>D <button>Click Me</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh yes, indeed, the second parameter of the forEach. That is what I needed! Thank you very much